# Material UI ClickAwayListener remain open on touchmove event

Tags: reactjs, touch, material-ui

I am inexperienced with mobile touch events so I am seeking some clarification. I have a Material UI `ClickAwayListener` which wraps a `Popper`. I want this `Popper` to remain open until the user clicks or taps outside. I found when testing on a touch device that the `onClickAway` function was invoked by a `touchmove` ([as expected](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events/Supporting_both_TouchEvent_and_MouseEvent#Event_order) when the user removes their finger).

I worked around this issue by using a `touchmove` event listener and state property that the user is moving on the screen. [A working example is here](https://codesandbox.io/s/rlljp5588p).

Is there a simpler solution to this? Is there some way to tell `ClickAwayListener` to ignore `touchend` when preceeded by a `touchmove`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an overlooked event sequence in Material UI. My PR to fix it has been accepted and will ship in the next release

The [issue I raised](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/13681) on github.

Comment: Hi, would you mind sharing the PR or issue link with the related discussion ?

Comment: Never mind, go it: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/13681